# The type or namespace name 'Devices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I found similar problems but any solution didn't help.
I wanna declare *private PhotoCamera photoCamera;* with *using Microsoft.Devices;*
but it's problem here.
I am creating Windows Phone 8.1 app using Visual Studio 2013. Am I should install some Reference ?

Thx in advance

Comment: Yes, it's in the Microsoft.Phone.dll assembly... do you have an assembly reference for that? But the namespace is also `Microsoft.Devices`, not `Microsoft.Device`.

Comment: Of course .Devices it's same problem

Comment: I don't think there's any "of course" about either of those. People make typos (as per your question, which still includes a typo) and people forget to include references. Please update your question to make this clearer.

Comment: @woochuck: what references do you have in your project?

Comment: @enkryptor Windows Phone 8.1, System.Device, ZXing, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 and some more

Comment: @woochuck: could you right-click your references, then choose "Copy References" and paste the text on the pastebin ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera class, you need to reference Microsoft.Phone assembly. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.photocamera(v=vs.105).aspx